# VisualForce Error: Id value is not valid for the Contact standard controller

Tags: error-handling, contacts, visualforce

This error is due to the Id is from !$User.Id not !Contact.Id. I don't know how to solve this, because I need the contact.id. Because I placed the VF page in a custom link and I want, when a user click over that link, fill the information with their contact fields. Below the code for the VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">  
   <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Personal Information" >
          <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Name}" />
          <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Phone}"/>
          <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.MobilePhone}"/>
          <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Email}"/>
          <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Birthdate}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockSection>

     <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Travel Information">
          <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Passport__c}"/>
          <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.Expiration_Date__c}"/>
          <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.VISA__c}"/>
          <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.VISA_Expiration_Date__c}"/>
          <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.European_Passport__c}"/>
          <apex:outputField value="{!Contact.European_Passport_Expiration_Date__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>    

     </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way will be to access your VF page with a link similar to `/apex/YourPageName?id=003...` where `003...` is the Id of the Contact you want to show.

Where have you placed the custom link? It will work best if it's either on Contact or on something Contact-related (Case maybe or some custom object that has a lookup to contact).

Can you post the screenshot of he link's definition? If its' on Contact then just change the link type to "Visualforce page" and you're done. If it's on something else (Case for example) then the type should be URL: `/apex/YourPageName?id={!Case.ContactId}`.

---

Edit after the comments/clarifications

Try something like that (you'll need an apex class + VF page):

```
public class PersonalInfoEditor{
    public Contact con {get; set;}

    public PersonalInfoEditor(){
        List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone, ... FROM Contact WHERE OwnerId = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1]; // use your lookup instead of my OwnerId here

        if(contacts.isEmpty()){
            con = new Contact(OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId()); // none found? let's prepare to save a new Contact for this user
        } else {
            con = contacts[0]; // found? then let's use him
        }
    }

    public void save(){
        upsert con;
    }
}

<apex:page controller="PersonalInfoEditor" tabStyle="Contact">  
   <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
              <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Personal Information" >
          <apex:inputField value="{!con.Phone}" />
          <apex:inputField value="{!con.Email}" />
          ...
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Is a custom link on the Home Page.

Comment: I've tried with VisualForce Page and URL as a Content Source, these two options shows the same error: Id value [userId] is not valid for the Contact standard controller.

Comment: PS: I don't know how to attach screenshots in this page. Sorry!

Comment: If it's on home page - which Contact you want to show then? You could hardcode the Id in the link (but that'd be a weird page). Or if there's some logic as to how you decide "this user should see data from this contact" - post it please (edit your question)? Images can be added by hitting the image icon in the question & answer editor. You need info from the Contact object or the info for "this" User? I have to say I'm bit confused...

Comment: I'll try to explain this, and yes is a bit confusing. Users of Salesforce has a Contact record related. Also we have a profile that only allows the load of Timecards. Is the only thing those users can perform over the system. Now I want to allow them to edit their personal information. That personal information is on the Contact Layout. That is why I want to create this custom link to allow the user edit they contact information (Only the fields selected on the VF page).

Comment: The contact that I want to show is the one related to the user. For example my User ID is 005E00000030LzU but my contact Id is 003E000000dZJ1l, this is the value that is valid for the Contact Standard Controller. Thanks, really, for your help!

Comment: Sorry, But I can't add an image I need at least 10 on reputation! :(

Comment: And how are the Contact & User linked, how do you know "this is the one"? For example - is there a lookup(Contact) field on the user? or would you match them by say same email address?

Comment: There is a lookup(User) on Contacts. When we create a new contact that is a resource, we search the user to assign they to the contact record.

Comment: Hi Sorry to bother, but you have any ideas about how do I need to proceed to solve this?

Comment: Hi Noelia! Have you seen the part after "Edit after the comments/clarifications"? I've answered on Dec 30th ;) Or if there are any problems - edit the question including errors you got or something.

Comment: Thanks...I'll try your suggestion! I'll let you know...the outcomes :)

Comment: Hi...I get this error: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.Name

Comment: Add all the fields you intend to show on the page to the `SELECT...` statement. So `SELECT Id, Name, Email, ... FROM Contact...`

Comment: I'm trying to add a en edit button and I can't. <apex:pageBlockButtons>
         <apex:commandButton action="{!edit}" value="Edit"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>

Comment: I need to give to my contacts the ability of edit the values showed!...I'm lost here, sorry!

Comment: Check the update (conversion from `outputField` to `inputField` and the `commandButton` that (when clicked) will try to save changes. But I'd say you should spend some time reading Visualforce documentation ;)

Comment: Thanks for all your help...the thing is that I'm not a developer, and I don't understand much the visualforce documentation. Thanks to people like you, I can achieve great things!